# Reload image doesn't refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function updateimage(){
    $("#fileimg").attr("src","path/to/image.jpg");
    $('#fileimg').fadeIn('slow');
    setTimeout(updateimage, 5000);
}
```

Hey,

I want to reload an image every 5 seconds but that doesn't work, it stays the same, but when you F5 the page it do refreshes. How can i refresh it every 5 sec normally that the image updates too?

Answer (score 6):

It's cached, so it doesn't need to reload. If you want to force a fresh load you need to make the browser think it's a different file:

```
function updateimage(){ 
    $("#fileimg").attr("src","path/to/image.jpg?" + new Date());  
    $('#fileimg').fadeIn('slow');  
    setTimeout(updateimage, 5000); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a solution that respects http caching? If the image only changes sometimes, it would be great not to force every client to do a complete reload.

E.g. I have a webcam pic that updates every 5 seconds. Even if each client does a ?dateMillis reload every 5 seconds, intermediate caches will still not correctly reuse the data between clients. Allowing standard cache timeouts (or even etag checks) to work would save a lot of resources.